# Is there a way to manage Google Calendar sharing through Zend Gdata or otherwise in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata-api, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a custom calendar app that is using Google Calendar as a base. I am wondering if there is a way through the Zend Gdata library to manage calendar sharing. From the documentation it does not appear so, but I noticed that some other languages have the ability (.Net, Python). If it's not possible through Gdata, is there another library out there that provides the ability in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

The Zend Framework Gdata seems to be based off the version 1 of the API. Version 2 is now out, and uses XML or JSON to communicate, so should be relatively easy to implement. See http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#SharingACalendar for implementation instructions.

Comment: This is a nice answer - but could be even better if you posted a bit of an abstract and a few minor examples for the OP. In general, just a link tends to lead to answers with broken references - but abstracts are useful to the community for a long time.